# Using SQL Server Polybase and CSV file as data source

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2019, polybase

Anybody that actually got this to work? To use a csv-file as a datasource with polybase? I've just get the error message below.

> Msg 105082, Level 16, State 1, Line 12. See the rest in code block.

Got the latest updates both of SQL Server 2019 EE, OS and ODBC and Microsoft Access Text Driver. The user has the right credentials. Creating the external data source is no problem, it's when trying creating the external table the error occurs. Can anybody see the any obvious error

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TOPSECRET_PSW';
GO
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE TestCSV
WITH 
( 
    LOCATION = 'odbc://localhost',
    CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=D:\APA\',
    PUSHDOWN = OFF
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.testCSV
(
     Header1 nvarchar(128)
    ,Header2 nvarchar(128)
 )
WITH
(
    LOCATION='[testCSV.csv]',
    DATA_SOURCE = TestCSV
)
```

> Msg 105082, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> 105082;Generic ODBC error: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x1608 Thread 0x3450 DBC 0x8d76d578                                                             Text'. Additional error <2>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]Invalid connection string attribute SERVER, SqlState: 01S00, NativeError: 8 Additional error <3>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]Invalid connection string attribute SERVER, SqlState: 01S00, NativeError: 8 Additional error <4>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]Invalid connection string attribute SERVER, SqlState: 01S00, NativeError: 8 Additional error <5>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]Invalid connection string attribute SERVER, SqlState: 01S00, NativeError: 8 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply latest SQL Server 2019 CU to get rid of that message. However, once that error disappears, I couldn't make it work on Docker, are you using a physical machine?

Comment: No, virtual machine (VMware). The machine has the latesed patch installed.

Comment: You need to add curly brackets, here's mine: CONNECTION_OPTIONS='Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; DBQ=C:\setup\Book1.xlsx;'

Comment: Isnt that curly brackets just for xlsx? in my case its cvs file I want as a "datasource". It didn' work.

Comment: I started from scratch. Re-installed everthing. All drivers,patches, Polybase. All in right order. Polybase last so all CU is included. Now I got this Msg 110813, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
100001;Failed to generate query plan.

Comment: I just found people are having the same problem, see here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-server-2019-polybase-100001-failed-to-generate-query-plan/m-p/2032135. Try casting decimal columns to float, or reinstall latest CU.

Comment: I even got this error by using the simplest csv file possible.

Comment: Have you already added curly brackets and the file name to your connection options?